# Having trouble initializing a struct in c++

Tags: c++, struct

I thought that to initialize a `struct` in C++ all you did was use the name of the `struct` and the variable.  However, I am getting a warning uninitialized in this function warning.

How do I initialized the `LPCPINFO cpinfo struct`?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

const int MAX_DEFAULTCHAR =   2;

const int MAX_LEADBYTES   =  12;

typedef struct _cpinfo {
    unsigned int MaxCharSize;
    char DefaultChar[MAX_DEFAULTCHAR];
    char LeadByte[MAX_LEADBYTES];
} CPINFO, *LPCPINFO;


int main() {

     LPCPINFO cpinfo;
     cpinfo->DefaultChar[0]= 1;
     cpinfo->DefaultChar[1]= 0;
     cpinfo->LeadByte[0] = cpinfo->LeadByte[1] = 0;
     cpinfo->MaxCharSize =  4;

     cout << cpinfo->DefaultChar[0] << " " << cpinfo->DefaultChar[1] << " "
         << cpinfo->LeadByte[0] << " " <<cpinfo->LeadByte[1] << " "
         << cpinfo->MaxCharSize
         << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you do use just the name of the structure, but `LPCPINFO` is not that.

Comment: Also, `typedef struct` is not necessary in a C++ program.  Maybe if you defined your structs the C++ way, you would have less issues with the code.

Comment: @Aaron `LPCINFO` is a pointer.  It isn't the struct -- that's why I stated my last comment.

Comment: That is no c++ (besides cout) - Please grab some books.

Comment: Please don't use `typedef` to hide pointer and reference attributes of a type, it makes it confusing for other developers and makes it unclear what the type really is even if you are using an obnoxious outdated pitifully dumb naming convention.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the author does not know basics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LPCPINFO` is defined as a pointer to a `CPINFO` struct (note the `*` in the `typedef`). You need to allocate the memory:

```
LPCPINFO cpinfo = new CPINFO();
```

Or you can just use the `CPINFO` struct:

```
CPINFO cpinfo;
cpinfo.DefaultChar[0] = 1;
//...
```

Comment: As to option 1 -- Too many new coders fall into the trap of unneedlessly allocating memory when all they need to do is declare an instance.

Comment: This is where knowledge of where the thing ends up is useful - on the stack or on the heap. This also requires knowledge of those two things :)

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a structure variable will look like this:

```
_cpinfo MyScructVar;
```

The name of your struct is _cpinfo, and you use this type to create variables of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Since you tagged this question as `C++`, it would make it a lot clearer if you defined your `struct` the C++ way:

```
struct _cpinfo {
    unsigned int MaxCharSize;
    char DefaultChar[MAX_DEFAULTCHAR];
    char LeadByte[MAX_LEADBYTES];
};
```

Then the `main` becomes this:

```
int main() 
{
    _cpinfo cpinfo;
    cpinfo.DefaultChar[0]= 1;
    cpinfo.DefaultChar[1]= 0;
    cpinfo.LeadByte[0] = cpinfo.LeadByte[1] = 0;
    cpinfo.MaxCharSize =  4;

    cout << cpinfo.DefaultChar[0] << " " << cpinfo.DefaultChar[1] << " "
    << cpinfo.LeadByte[0] << " " <<cpinfo.LeadByte[1] << " "
    << cpinfo.MaxCharSize
    << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

More than likely, you were confused with the `typedef` name, and assumed it was the struct itself.

Also, if you want a pointer to the struct, then declare a pointer to the struct:

`_cpinfo *whatever;`

Hiding pointers behind a typedef may be used throughout your favorite `C` API, but I don't recommend doing this in your own code, as pointed out by @CaptainOblivious.